# Create word documents from observations in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, create, print-templates

In my QGIS project (3.32.2) I have one point and one polygon vector layer. In both layers, a row (observation) corresponds to a mapped natural object. In the columns (fields), the objects are described according to different criteria (e.g., size, plant species).

Is there a tool with which I can create a Word file from each row of the attribute table? In addition, photos should be inserted in each Word file.

I have not found an answer to this question in the QGIS support forums.

Comment: Have look at the atlas and/or report fonction (https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html#generate-an-atlas and https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_reports.html#creating-a-report) But if you need a word document with picture and no map, export your data to excel and and convert it to word (but this is not the right place to ask about this process...)

Comment: Maybe try some plugins that can perform HTML export